# Sending NSMutableArray OR NSDictionary to php to mysql

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, nsmutablearray

In my application, i made an activity to get input numbers from the user, the number of textfields for input data is different each time, it's a tableView and each cell has a textfield, i managed to store all the numbers in a `NSMutableArray`, and I've been looking into how to pass it to my php, I can't seem to find something to help me, and it can't be send as NSString using "`StringWithFormat`".

Should `NSMutableArray` Be changed into `NSDictionary` ? How Do i Send it to my php code ?

I am using `AFNetworking` to manage all my connections and it's great, just got stuck on sending an array.

each object in my `NSMutableArray` consists of

```
StudentName, StudentMark, StudentID
```

any suggestions or good tutorials i can learn from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFNetworking, by default, uses the `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` (which creates `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests). This is not well suited for sending an array of values (esp an array of dictionaries).

You have a couple of options, assuming you have an array of `students`:

1. Manually use `NSJSONSerialization` to encode the array of dictionaries into a string, and then pass that as a parameter in a dictionary:

   ```
   NSError *error;
   NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:students options:0 error:&error];
   NSAssert(jsonData, @"Problem encoding JSON: %@", error);
   NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   [manager POST:urlString parameters:@{@"students": jsonString} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
   }];
   ```

   If you do that, your server code would grab `$_POST['students']`, and then `json_decode` that.
2. Change the web service to accept JSON requests (i.e. an `application/json` request rather than an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests).

   ```
   manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

   [manager POST:urlString parameters:students success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
       NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
       NSLog(@"%@", error);
   }];
   ```

   If you do that, though, it requires a more fundamental change in your web service to accept JSON requests (e.g., rather than using `$_POST`, you'd manually grab the input and JSON decode it:

   ```
   <?php

       // read the raw post data

       $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
       $raw_post_data = '';
       while (!feof($handle)) {
           $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
       }
       fclose($handle);

       // decode the JSON into an associative array

       $request = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);

       // you can now access the associative array, $request,
       // e.g. save it to your database

       // let's assume you built a `$response` dictionary summarizing 
       // the success or failure of the above code, now let's output it:  

       $raw_response = json_encode($response);

       // specify headers

       header("Content-Type: application/json");
       header("Content-Length: " . strlen($raw_response));

       // output response

       echo $raw_response;
   ?>
   ```

The first option is probably easiest, but lacks a certain elegance (embedding JSON within a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request). The latter option (changing web service to accept JSON requests) would require a little more work, though (e.g. once you have one web service request using JSON, you might want the whole web service to use JSON consistently).

Comment: thanks for the help, i'm trying to make it work, i posted what i tried here, if you care to take a look 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31235801/how-to-retrieve-nsmutablearray-in-php-side

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about IOS and objective-c so I don't know how they send post data to a server. The platforms that I know about allow the sending of JSON and that is what would be used to send an array to PHP. PHP then simply [json_decodes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the data into a PHP array. So, if you use NSJSONSerialization (just looked that up) you can send your data and process it in PHP.