# How to retrieve nsmutablearray in php side

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, arrays

Using this code, the nsmutablearray "StudentDataToSendArray" is sent to the php, ' i think so ' ...

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager POST:@"http://****/iStartTest.php" parameters:@{@"Student_TotalAverage": StudentDataToSendArray} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"data = %@", responseObject);
    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

in the php side, using this code to get the array

```
$Student_TotalAverage=$_POST['Student_TotalAverage'];

$Response = array("Count" => count($Student_TotalAverage));
echo json_encode($Response);
```

the echo of array size is infact correct.

is this all right ?

and if so, i need to get the array values.

this is the code for the array

```
NSMutableArray *StudentDataToSendArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

this is the NSObject Holding all values in each object added to the nsmutablearray

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *StudentNameNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *StudentIDNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *SubjectNameNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *SubjectIDNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ClassNameNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ClassIDNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Exam_IDNow;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *MarkNow;
```

adding object to the nsmurablearray StudentDataToSend

```
 [StudentDataToSendArray addObject:SingleStudentDetails];
```

i tried this code, but i keep getting a null value

```
$temp = current($Student_TotalAverage)-> StudentName;
echo json_encode($temp);
```

or

```
$temp = $Student_TotalAverage[0]['StudentName'];
echo json_encode($temp);


<?php header("Content-type: text/json"); ?>
<?php 

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("*****.*****.com","*****","******","******") or die ( mysqli_error($MySQL_Handle) ); 

$sSQL= 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8'; 
mysqli_query($con,$sSQL) or die ('Can\'t charset in DataBase'); 

$test = "SET NAMES utf8";
mysqli_query($con,$test);

$Student_TotalAverage=$_POST['Student_TotalAverage'];

$XcodeResponse = array("status" => count($Student_TotalAverage));
echo json_encode($XcodeResponse);

// Close conn
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: What is `StudentDataToSendArray`? You have to show us what it contains (or better, create simplified [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the problem). But if it's array of dictionaries as suggested by your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31226607), there are serious limitations as to what you can send with the standard `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. Work-arounds include either converting `StudentDataToSendArray` to JSON before sending it, and converting it back in the PHP code, or, better, refactor server to accept JSON requests.

Comment: edited the code, does that provide better understanding ?

Comment: My previous comments that you can't just put this in the `parameters` of the AFNetworking `POST` method still stands. You either have to change request to JSON request, or manually encode JSON string before sending request, and manually decode it in the server code. Frankly, the fact that you're talking about array of custom objects complicates it further because you probably have to build array of `NSDictionary` objects first, and then proceed as outlined earlier.

Comment: thanks, i will keep working on this, and will post an answer hopefully when successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many thanks to @Rob for directing me to the right direction, took me a while but all worked out well
the answer to my question is this

adding the values from the tableViewCells to NSMutableArray and then adding the nsmutablearray to nsmutabedictionary with key as RowNumber

```
 NSMutableArray *temparray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init ];
    [temparray addObject:stID];
    [temparray addObject:stname];
    [temparray addObject:subjectID];
    [temparray addObject:subjectname];
    [temparray addObject:classID];
    [temparray addObject:classname];
    [temparray addObject:examID];
    [temparray addObject:mark];

    [DictionaryToSend setObject:temparray forKey:currrow];
```

then passing the nsmutabledictionary "DictionaryToSend" to the php page with this code

```
NSString *URLString = @"http://*********/*****/iStartTest.php";
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:@{@"DictionaryToSave": DictionaryToSend}
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    }
          failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
```

Then Reading the data from the php page and inserting it to mysql database

```
$Student_Details=$_POST['DictionaryToSave'];

$ww = 0;

while ($ww < count($Student_Details))
{
$StudentID = $Student_Details[$ww][0];
$StudentFullName = $Student_Details[$ww][1];
$SubjectID = $Student_Details[$ww][2];
$SubjectName = $Student_Details[$ww][3];
$ClassNo = $Student_Details[$ww][4];
$ClassName = $Student_Details[$ww][5];
$Exam_ID = $Student_Details[$ww][6];
$Mark = $Student_Details[$ww][7];

// do whatever with the data here

$ww++;
}
```

any improvements to the code are most welcome :)